# Error rendering quarto project after update of TinyTex

Tags: r, latex, rstudio, quarto

I encountered discrepancies in PDF renderings between my setup and my colleague's. He was on TinyTeX version 2024.2, while I was not updated. Consequently, I upgraded TinyTeX using "quarto install tool tinytex." However, immediately after updating and attempting to render the same document, I encountered an error:

```
updating existing packages
finding package for ngerman.ldf
(babel)
ERROR:
compilation failed- no matching packages
Package babel Error: Unknown option 'ngerman'. Either you misspelled it
(babel) or the language definition file ngerman.ldf
(babel) was not found.
(babel) There is a locale ini file for this language.
(babel) If it’s the main language, try adding `provide=*'
(babel) to the babel package options.
```

I also restarted rstudio, but with no luck..

```
doing a "quarto check", I get:
[✓] Checking tools....................OK
TinyTeX: v2024.02
Chromium: 869685

[✓] Checking LaTeX....................OK
Using: TinyTex
Path: /Users/dh/Library/TinyTeX/bin/universal-darwin
Version: 2023
```

For me it looks like rstudio ist still using TinyTex 2023.

according to suggestions i tried to install language packages again:

```
(base) sudo tlmgr install texlive-lang-german
tlmgr: package repository https://ftp.agdsn.de/pub/mirrors/latex/dante/systems/texlive/tlnet (not verified: gpg unavailable)
tlmgr install: package texlive-lang-german not present in repository.
tlmgr: action install returned an error; continuing.
tlmgr: An error has occurred. See above messages. Exiting.

(base) d-mbp:texlive dh$ sudo tlmgr install babel-german
tlmgr: package repository https://ctan.mc1.root.project-creative.net/systems/texlive/tlnet (not verified: gpg unavailable)
tlmgr install: package already present: babel-german
```

Did not work.

i ran tlmgr list --only-installed | grep german to display all german language packages:

```
i apalike-german: A copy of apalike.bst with German localization
i babel-german: Babel support for documents written in German
i biblatex-german-legal: Comprehensive citation style for German legal texts
i bibleref-german: German adaptation of bibleref
i collection-langgerman: German
i datetime2-german: German language module for the datetime2 package
i german: Support for German typography
i glossaries-german: German language module for glossaries package
i hyphen-german: German hyphenation patterns.
i lshort-german: German version of A Short Introduction to LaTeX2e: LaTeX2e-Kurzbeschreibung
i mfnfss: Packages to typeset oldgerman and pandora fonts in LaTeX
```

apparently german and babel-german are installed, but non of them work when i set them in the yaml-file. but english does work fine. ngerman is missing on the list, despite the fact it rendered correctly before the update of tinytex with the exact same package.

System (me and the colleague's):

- arm-based macbook
- rstudio Version 2023.12.1+402 (2023.12.1+402)
- R Version: 4.3.2